# How do I find an application that's already installed on Knoppix?

Tags: linux, package-management, application, knoppix

I have created a bootable USB drive with Knoppix. It works fine, but I was specifically looking for chntpw and a tool to wipe a HDD. This question is about where to find a package (chntpw) that Synaptic Package Manager says is already installed.

How do I find an application that's already installed? I have looked through the menus, but I don't see it anywhere.

Thanks,
Jono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dpkg -L chntpw` to show package contents, then look for paths in `/usr/bin`, `/bin/` etc.

e.g `dpkg -L wget` shows the following output,

```
# dpkg -L wget
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/wget
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/wget
/usr/share/doc/wget/README
/usr/share/doc/wget/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/wget/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/wget/MAILING-LIST
/usr/share/doc/wget/copyright
/usr/share/doc/wget/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/info
/usr/share/info/wget.info.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/wget.1.gz
/etc
/etc/wgetrc
```

Then you know `/usr/bin/wget` is the binary file to execute